# AWK Split File every n-th Row but group IDs together

Tags: unix, awk, split

Lets assume I have the following file `text.txt`:

```
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
6
7
7
8
9
9
9
10
11
11
11
14
15
```

I want to split this into multiple files by every 5th data row, but if the number of the next row is identical it should still end up in the same file. Header should be in every file, but that could also be ignored and reintroduced later.
This means something like this:

```
text.txt.1
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
1
2
2
3
3
3

text.txt.2
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
4
4
4
5
5

text.txt.3
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
6
7
7
8
9
9
9

text.txt.4
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
10
11
11
11
14

text.txt.5
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
15
```

So I was thinking about something like this:

```
awk 'NR%5==1 && $1!=prev{i++;prev=$1}{print > FILENAME"."i}' test.txt
```

Both statements work by itself but not together.. is that possible using awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^@/ {
    hdr = hdr $0 ORS
    next
}
( (++numLines) % 5 ) == 1 {
    if ( $0 == prev ) {
        --numLines
    }
    else {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME "." (++numBlocks)
        printf "%s", hdr > out
        numLines = 1
    }
}
{
    print > out
    prev = $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk text.txt
```

```
$ head text.txt.*
==> text.txt.1 <==
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
1
2
2
3
3
3

==> text.txt.2 <==
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
4
4
4
5
5

==> text.txt.3 <==
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
6
7
7
8
9
9
9

==> text.txt.4 <==
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
10
11
11
11
14

==> text.txt.5 <==
@something
@somethingelse
@anotherthing
15
```

Comment: Sorry took me a while to test it, but that works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question.
With your example, this would work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1;}/\@/{header= header == ""? $0 : header "\n" $0; next}c>=5 && $1!=prev{i++;c=0;}{if(!c) print header>FILENAME"."i; print > FILENAME"."i;c++;prev=$1;}' test.txt
```

You need strip the header out, and set a counter (`c` in above), `NR` is just current line number of the input, it will not meet your needs when the actual lines are not times of 5.

Break it up and improve a tiny bit:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1;}
  /\@/{header= header == ""? $0 : header ORS $0; next}
  c>=5 && $1!=prev{i++;c=0;}
  !c {print header>FILENAME"."i;}
  {print > FILENAME"."i;c++;prev=$1;}
  ' test.txt
```

---

To solve the potential problems mentioned in the comment:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}
  /\@/{header= header == ""? $0 : header ORS $0; next}
  c>=5 && $1!=prev{i++;c=0}
  !c {close(f);f=(FILENAME"."i);print header>f}
  {print>f;c++;prev=$1}
  ' test.txt
```

or check [Ed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458007/5403468) which is more precise and different platforms/versions compatible.

Comment: `print > FILENAME"."i` is undefined behavior per POSIX, it needs to be `print > (FILENAME"."i)` or you'll get syntax errors in some awks. If you dont close the output files as you go you'll also get a "too many open files" failure from some awks once you get over about 15 output files.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the reminder. Precise as always   @EdMorton

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  outFile="test.txt"
  count=1
}
/@/{
  header=(header?header ORS:"")$0
  next
}
{
  arr[$0]=(arr[$0]?arr[$0] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
  print header > (outFile count)
  for(i in arr){
    num=split(arr[i],arr2,"\n")
    print arr[i] > (outFile count)
    len+=num
    if(len>=5){ len=0 }
    if(len==0){
      close(outFile count)
      count++
      print header > (outFile count)
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```